# How do I get a list of all of the available dbus properties?

Tags: appmenu, dbus

How do I get a list of all of the available dbus properties for example `org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.Const`? Especially to control window managers, like xfwm. And how would I receive the global menu in `python-dbus`?

Like if I started Firefox how could I grab it's global menu data and display it, just like unity's global menubar?

Comment: Similar question on UNIX/Linux site →[linux - A list of available D-Bus services - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46301/a-list-of-available-d-bus-services)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using the d-feet tool?

```
sudo apt-get install d-feet
```

[image]

Try that and see if you make progress.

Comment: Cool I'll try it is there a command line version or a method in `python-dbus` that I can use for development?

Answer (score 2):

ref:
`man gdbus`
`man qdbus`

In a terminal window run

```
qdbus | sort -V |                                                      \
sed -u -e 's/\(.*\)/echo =========== \1 ========== ;                   \
gdbus introspect -r  --session  -o \/ --only-properties -d \1/g' |     \
bash
```

Standard interfaces are listed first so all properties for them are found - the script will halt on the first missing interface DBus address that is listed - ...

(To avoid this halt, preprocess `qdbus | sort -V` to a file, remove missing interfaces and then `sed` that file.)

The same can be done for `--system` instead of `--session` starting with `qdbus --system`.

To do just `org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.Const`

```
gdbus introspect -r --session -o / --only-properties -d org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.Const
```

Bookmark:
[How do I get a list of all of the available dbus properties?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147568/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-of-the-available-dbus-properties/190695#190695)