# how to list opened nautilus tabs with qdbus?

Tags: nautilus, scripts, dbus, tabs

I am trying to dig into qdbus for nautilus to get a list of opened tabs; I managed to do this so far:

```
sites=(`qdbus |grep nautilus -i`);
for siteSrc in ${sites[@]};do
  list=(`qdbus $siteSrc`);
  for path in ${list[@]}; do
    qdbus $siteSrc $path |sed -r "s|.*|$siteSrc $path &|";
  done;
done |sort -u #|grep paths -i
```

for ex.: I was able to get a list of selected files with

```
qdbus org.gnome.NautilusApplication /org/nautilus_actions/DBus/Tracker/0 org.nautilus_actions.DBus.Tracker.Properties1.GetSelectedPaths
```

but I cant find a clue for opened tabs locations? (so we can use on scripts to restore them later)

Answer (score 1):

From this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/190695/46437), I got to this

```
gdbus introspect -r --session -o / --only-properties -d org.gnome.Nautilus |grep "OpenLocations ="
```

easier one

```
qdbus org.gnome.Nautilus /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.OpenLocations
```

Tho to open tabs in nautilus thru command line, to the date, seem impossible.

Comment: [this script](https://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh) can restart nautilus with previously opened tabs but has limitations